# In a Docker environment, DDL creates tables for one test class – but fails to do so for another. Why?

Tags: java, spring, docker, hibernate, testing

I have a Docker-contained REST app. It has a few test classes, including `UserQuestionRestControllerTest` and `UserQuestionCommentControllerTest`. They look something like this

```java
    @Test
    @Sql(executionPhase = BEFORE_TEST_METHOD, value = BASE_SCRIPT_PATH + "GetCommentTest/before.sql") // e.g. attempts to insert into the security join table accounts_permissions
    @Sql(executionPhase = AFTER_TEST_METHOD, value = BASE_SCRIPT_PATH + "GetCommentTest/after.sql")
    public void getCommentTest() throws Exception {
        MockHttpServletResponse response = mockMvc.perform(get(BASE_URI + 1)
                        .header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, token))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andReturn()
                .getResponse();
    // asserts
```

The former test class, `UserQuestionRestControllerTest`, completes successfully while the latter class's test methods all fail for the same reason – 401, "not authorized"

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200> but was:<401>
Expected :200
Actual   :401
```

I examined the verbose console output and noticed this. The first exception that pops up is `ClosedChannelException`

```
Caused by: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException: null
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.WindowsAsynchronousFileChannelImpl.implRead(WindowsAsynchronousFileChannelImpl.java:516)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousFileChannelImpl.read(AsynchronousFileChannelImpl.java:229)
    at com.github.dockerjava.transport.NamedPipeSocket$AsynchronousFileByteChannel.read(NamedPipeSocket.java:117)
    at java.base/java.nio.channels.Channels$2.read(Channels.java:238)
```

It doesn't tell me much, and at any rate it seems it doesn't actually cause `UserQuestionCommentControllerTest`'s tests to fail. After all, when I examined the console output of the successfully run `UserQuestionRestControllerTest`, it, too, included that exception

[image]

Back to the original console output. The next thing of note is Hibernate's attempt to drop a foreign key of a table `accounts_permissions`. It's a join table and contains two columns: `account_id` and `permission_id`. It serves to provide security information on user roles

```java
    @NotNull
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "accounts_permissions", // ← here it is
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "account_id", nullable = false),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "permission_id", nullable = false),
            uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"account_id", "permission_id"}))
    private Set<Permission> permissions = new HashSet<>();
```

```
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "alter table accounts_permissions drop constraint FKjfqhtvqauv3ign74mp1dybsyr" via JDBC Statement
```

However, Hibernate finds out that `accounts_permissions` does not exist and throws an exception (instead of creating the table)

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "accounts_permissions" does not exist
```

Importantly, both run configurations are identical. The only VM option in both cases is the profile, `-Dspring.profiles.active=test`

[image]

[image]

Now, I have two YML-configurations. One is called `application-local.yml`. It sits in the `resources` folder which is a sibling to `java`, *the source root*. It *contains* datasource information. It, I believe, is not relevant though I'll include it just in case I'm wrong (which very well might be)

```yaml
server:
  port: ${SERVER_PORT:8080}

spring:
  application:
    name: stack-overflow
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://${POSTGRES_SERVER:localhost}:${POSTGRES_PORT:5411}/${POSTGRES_DATABASE:stack_overflow_postgres}
    username: ${POSTGRES_USERNAME:postgres}
    password: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD:postgres123}
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
    hibernate.ddl-auto: ${POSTGRES_DDL_AUTO:create}
    show-sql: ${POSTGRES_SHOW_SQL:true}

jwt:
  secret:
    key: abrakadabra
  expiration:
    hours: 10

springdoc:
  api-docs:
    path: /docs/v3/api-docs
  swagger-ui:
    path: /docs/swagger-ui/index.html
```

Notice the DDL set to `create`. I also have a separate configuration file, `application-test.yml`. It sits in the resources root which is a sibling to *the test root*. This YML *doesn't* contain datasource info (but remember the "Question" test class runs with no issues)

```yaml
spring:
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
    hibernate.ddl-auto: ${POSTGRES_DDL_AUTO:create}
    show-sql: ${POSTGRES_SHOW_SQL:true}

jwt:
  secret:
    key: abrakadabra
  expiration:
    hours: 10
```

I am new to Docker so my bet is I made some rookie mistake in that department

In case I didn't mention some important details, here's [my repo](https://github.com/NadChel/stack-overflow-1). I know that questions on SO are supposed to be self-contained, but in my opinion, information accessible remotely is better than information not accessible at all. If you suggest moving some parts of the code from the repo here, I'll gladly consider that suggestion

**UPD:** Unfortunately, I realized after the publication that I didn't push the commit to the repository. I am sorry for that. I corrected that mistake, and now you can actually see the code in question

**UPD2:** I am told it's because the tables are not yet created by the time an instance of my test class is created. Can you suggest alternative solutions to reduce code duplication so that I don't request the token at the start of each method?